# Install specific version using laravel installer

Tags: laravel

As of now, if I use this command

```
laravel new blog
```

It will create a laravel project with the latest version like 5.2, but what if I want to install a specific version, ie. version 5.1?

UPDATE:: I am looking for laravel installer command, is there is any option/parameter for specific version installation?

Answer (score 158):

Using composer you can specify the version you want easily by running

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.1.*" myProject
```

Using the 5.1.* will ensure that you get all the latest patches in the 5.1 branch.

Comment: Could not make an older version (5.3.*) using the Laravel installer version 1.4.1. Instead I had to use composer as per above.

Comment: Is there a way to make 'new' create all new projects as the most updated version?

Answer (score 105):

use

```
laravel new blog --version

Example laravel new blog --5.1
```

You can also use the composer method

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel app "5.1.*"
```

here, app is the name of your project

please see the documentation for laravel 5.1 [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1)

> UPDATE:

The above commands are no longer supports so please use

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.1.*" appName
```

Comment: This answer is very similar to the other answers. It is good to add an answer but please make sure that your answer adds new and useful information that is not in the others.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all; the original question is asking specifically about installing laravel with the `laravel/installer` package (see [https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/installer](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/installer)), not with the `composer create-project` command

Comment: This answer is invalidated since Feb 15, 2017
https://github.com/laravel/installer/commit/304809c2dd9bdaa0ba2183b122aaf77ea5bb0fb4#diff-2f97ce541989fd5777bb883c213d1805

Comment: Hello, I know that the answer was 5 year ago, but I tryed "laravel new blog --7" but dont work tell me the "--7" option does not exist

Comment: @MauEspaña Laravel don't have the option. please use composer for this 
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog

Answer (score 19):

You can use composer method
like

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1"
```

Or here is the composer file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Via composer installing specific version **10.***

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name
```

using composer installing specific version **9.***

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.* project_name
```

using composer installing specific version **8.***

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.* project_name
```

using composer installing specific version **7.***

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 project_name
```

To install specific version **6.*** and below use the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name "6.*"
```

Answer (score 15):

use **laravel new blog --5.1**
make sure you must have laravel installer 1.3.4 version.

Comment: `laravel help -- new` to view the documentation for the `laravel new` command

Comment: Not working (Installer 1.4.1). Are they playing games with this option or what?

Comment: This answer is invalidated since Feb 15, 2017
https://github.com/laravel/installer/commit/304809c2dd9bdaa0ba2183b122aaf77ea5bb0fb4#diff-2f97ce541989fd5777bb883c213d1805

Comment: seems like a pretty basic feature, sad they removed it

Answer (score 10):

The direct way as mentioned in the documentation:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*"
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation

Answer (score 7):

### Year 2022

Since Laravel 5.2 (2017) it is not possible to install a specific Laravel Version via `Laravel Installer`. Use instead `composer create-project`. For example:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "7.*"`

```sh
// That will install Version the latest version of Laravel 7.
// would install: 
"laravel/framework": "^7.29",
```

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.*"`

```sh
// would install:
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
```

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Would install the latest Laravel version on your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

For newer version of laravel:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel=5.5.* project_name
```

Answer (score 3):

From Laravel 6, Now It's working with the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to

```bash
laravel new my-project --branch 9.x
```

Comment: How does this additional argument change anything from [this >7 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154309/1255289)?

Comment: I'm not sure this works:

```php
laravel new my-project --branch 9.x
<snip>
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./my-project"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can find all version install code [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) by changing the version of laravel doc

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourProjectName "5.1.*"
```

above code for creating laravel 5.1 version project.
see more in laravel doc. happy coding!!

Answer (score -1):

you can use this command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.*.* exam-app
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is this really different enough from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66026346/4294399 to justify a new answer?

Comment: when i run this  stackoverflow.com/a/66026346/4294399 i got error.

Answer (score -1):

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name "version_num"

Example ::
suppose, i would like to create a new project called- `blog`
where i would like to use laravel `6.0` LTS version,,
following that command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*"
```