# Problem with installation of a specific laravel version

Tags: php, laravel

Once I try to install Laravel version 5.2 on  Windows, it is displaying the error shown. Other newer versions are installing successfully.

I have a PHP version 5.6.40 and the composer is installed.

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Comment: what steps you followed ? did you run `composer install` command

Comment: Yes, the composer is already installed.

Comment: Run `composer update`

Comment: Check for vendor folder. If not exists then run `composer update`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install specific version using laravel installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149812/install-specific-version-using-laravel-installer)

Answer (score 0):

We got an error because we have missing vendor folder in our project, The vendor directory contains our Composer dependencies.

**Need /vendor** folder because all packages are there and including all the classes Laravel uses, A problem can be solved after following just two steps:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```