# How to install the latest version of Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was trying to install the latest Laravel version (8.x) using the command I found on the documentation `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app` but it keeps download version 5.5.50, I cleared the cache for the composer and installed it again but still doesn't download version 8.x, what is the problem?

Comment: Please share more details. Packagist does not list such a version

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply specify a desired version within the command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app "8.5.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this happened to me. (It downloaded 7 when I wanted 8)

The cause was it was automatically downloading the latest that my system could support. As I had an older version of php (7.2) it was automatically downloading an old version of laravel. After updating it allowed me to download latest.

Check the other requirements of laravel too and check that there isn't also something else holding it back

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps to install Laravel 8.xV project

1. composer -v(check your composer version)
2. composer global require laravel/installer
3. laravel new projectName

Answer (score 0):

laravel automatically downloading according to your computer PHP version. Therefore you have to latest PHP version to download the latest laravel version. Read more about laravel 8 download and install. https://www.easycodeonline.com/article/how-to-download-and-install-laravel-8-on-your-computer

Answer (score 0):

1. First check whether composer installed or not.
2. If **YES** go to your drive->xampp/htdocs path type command **composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name**
3. If **NO** install latest version of composer globally from https://getcomposer.org/download/ .
4. To check the composer version write command **composer -v** or **composer --version**.
5. To know the detail of laravel 8 check the laravel8 official link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar issue and i resolved it by simply us `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel mp_notification_system "8.*"` and laravel will install the latest version of laravel 8. You can use the same approach for other laravel versions. Eg, `5.*, 6.*, 8.*, 9.*` ... I hope that helps out.

For more details, visit [Install specific version using laravel installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149812/install-specific-version-using-laravel-installer)